# Get all combinations of a string/array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code that will return all possible combinations of a string or array. But the code I have written doesn't consider repeating the characters as a possible combination. This is my code -

```js
function combinations(str) {
    var fn = function(n, r, q) {
        if (!n && !r)
            return;
        if (!r) {
            q.push(n);
        } else {
            fn(n + r[0], r.slice(1), q);
            fn(n, r.slice(1), q);
        }
        return q;
    }
    return fn("", str, []);
}

console.log(combinations("abcd"));
```

And the output is

> ```
> [ 'abcd',   'abc',   'abd',   'ab',   'acd',   'ac',   'ad',   'a',   'bcd',   'bc',   'bd',   'b',   'cd',   'c',   'd' ]
> ```

But I want to write a code which will consider even repetition of the characters for example "abcd" should give "aabd" , "abac", "abbb" etc. such kind of results along with the above mentioned output.

There is no limit on how many times each character can get repeated but there will be a limit on the size of the string. For example if the string is of length 4 then all output string should also be of length 4 or less.

Any suggestions how I can do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: See [CodeReview - Generate all possible combinations of letters in a word](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57161/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-letters-in-a-word)

Comment: Allowing repetition causes an infinite result size.

Comment: let us know the repetition limit. If not, it does not make sense.

Comment: There is no repetition limit. However there will be a limit on the size of the output string . Like if you enter a string of length 8 then all combinations of length 8 should get generated . I'll add that to the question